# Problema no footer html+css

Tags: html, css

A parte sobre não aparece no footer
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<footer id="rodape">
<div id="endereco">
<div>
    <h2>Endereço:</h2>
    <p>Rua Alcides Lima, 150 bl6 apt 201</p>  
    </div>
</div>

<div id="redes">
<h2>Rede Sociais:</h2>
    <div>
    <p>Facebook</p>
    <p>Twitter</p>
    <p>Intagram</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sobree">
<h2>Sobre esse Site:</h2>
<p>Projeto de Web Design da turma 3508DW Professor: TIO DAIVISSON</p>
</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

parte css:

```
#rodape{
    background-color: black;    
    height: 450px;
}

#endereco{
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: impact;
    width: 22%;
    float: left;
}
h2{
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: impact;
}
#redes{
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: impact;
    width: 22%;
    display: inline-block;
}
}

#sobree{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: impact;
    width: 22%;
```

Answer (score 2):

Está sobrando um `}` em `#redes`:

```
#redes{
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: impact;
    width: 22%;
    display: inline-block;
}
} <------ aqui
```

Está **faltando** um `}` em:

```
#sobree{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: impact;
    width: 22%;

 < --------------- Aqui
```

Com certeza foi erro de digitação, podem haver mais, mas só olhando o CSS todo.

Código corrigido:

```
#rodape{
    background-color: black;    
    height: 450px;
}

#endereco{
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: impact;
    width: 22%;
    float: left;
}
h2{
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: impact;
}
#redes{
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: impact;
    width: 22%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#sobree{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: impact;
    width: 22%;
}
```